# Directory filtering Maven

Tags: maven

I want to filter directory and its content based on profile. Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>properties</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/${env}/ucm.properties</filter>
    </filters>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>int</id>
        <properties>
            <env>int</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <properties>
            <env>uat</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>stag</id>
        <properties>
            <env>stag</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And this is my project structure:

[image]

But when it is building the jar it is copying all the folders (int, uat, stag, prod) inside it.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Be aware that it is a bad practice to include environment specific configuration in your Maven Project. You should only specify defaults. There are several threads here at stackoverflow which describe how you should refer to environment specific configuration.

Comment: @RobertScholte could you please tell me why it is bad practice?

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices is a fine article. Keep in mind that application and configuration are 2 separate things:  a change of configuration should never require a new build of the application. There are several ways to access configuration from an application (see article), so there's no need to bundle them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  section in your resource declaration. Like that:

```
    ...   
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>properties</targetPath>
        <includes>
          <include>${env}/*</include> <!-- including only the associated profile dir -->
          <include>env.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    ...
```

I don't know if the `${env}` property will work there, else maybe `${project.activeProfiles[0].id}` will work

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html for more info